# Correction factor for calculating standard error when drawing sample without replacement - derivation

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics, standard-error

When drawing a sample of size n from population of size N

This relationship holds

$$ SE\space when\space  drawing\space  sample\space  without\space  replacement\space  =\space  correction\space  factor\space  *\space  SE\space  when\space  drawing\space  with\space  replacement$$

where

$$ correction\space factor = \sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}} $$

N = size of population

n = size of sample

I would like to know how this relationship was derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have an urn with $M$ red marbles and $N-M$ blue marbles. You can say that $N$ is the population. Then you draw $x$ red marbles and $n-x$ blue marbles, where $n$ is the sample size. Then the random variable $X$ is hypergeometric distributed. Therefore the sample has a variance of $Var(X)=n\cdot \frac{M}{N}\cdot \left(1-\frac{M}{N} \right)\cdot \frac{N-n}{N-1}$. We can  replace $\frac{M}{N}$ by $p$ and get $Var(X)=n\cdot p\cdot \left(1-p \right)\cdot  \frac{N-n}{N-1}$. And the variance of the sample mean is $Var\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}\right)=Var(\overline X)=\frac{p\cdot \left(1-p \right)}{n}\cdot  \frac{N-n}{N-1}$

It is obvious that $\frac{p\cdot \left(1-p \right)}{n}$ is the  sample mean variance of binomial distributed variables ($\overline Y$) divided by $n$. For a large $ n$ the distribution of $\overline Y$ can  approximated by the normal distribution (central limit theorem): $Var\left(\overline Y \right)\approx \frac{\sigma^2}{ n}$ The variance of $\overline X $ then is approximately $Var\left(\overline Y \right)\cdot \frac{N-n}{N-1}$. To obtain  the approximated standard error of the mean  we take the sqare root:

$$\sigma_{\overline x}\approx \underbrace{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}}_{\text{SE with replacement} }\cdot \sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}}$$

Comment: `For large N and M the fraction M/N can be regarded as constant and we replace M/N by p` Is this assumption required? I think we can get to the next step without this assumption.

Comment: @q126y I don´t see a way to omit this step, since we need a more or less  constant p.

Comment: But we don't need constant p. This shows a proof without considering it constant http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~gptesler/186/slides/186_hypergeom_17-handout.pdf

Kindly correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @q126y Good catch. If M and N are large the variance become the variance of a binomial sample, since $\frac{N-n}{N-1}\approx 1$. But this is not needed here. I´ll  correct it.

Comment: Hello Mr callculus, this derivation is for cases where our variable can have only two values (0,1). What about cases where the variable can have any value? How would we derive that relationship? Thanks.

Comment: @q126y What we need is a distribution of the variable(s). Do you have a specific example?

Comment: Hey I have found the proof on page 8 of this pdf http://home.iitk.ac.in/~shalab/sampling/chapter2-sampling-simple-random-sampling.pdf

The linked pdf has a few typos.

I have one confusion though. Due to lack of space, please find my complete response here

https://i.imgur.com/QLIsD7i.png

SRSWOR = simple random sample without replacement.

Thanks

Comment: Mr callculus, did you get time to see my comment? Thanks